# undefined class when I use fetch_object [mysqli]

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm trying to learn OOP, but I get the following error whenever I use fetch_object method:

Error I'm getting

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Users' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\learn_classes\index.php on line 22

php code:

```
use classes\Database;
use classes\Users;

include 'classes/start.php';


$conn = Database::connection();
$get_data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM `users`');

while ($data = $get_data->fetch_object('Users')){
    echo $data->id;

}
```

I tried to use require, but that didn't work either!

user class:

```
namespace classes;


class Users
{
    public $id;
    protected $userType;
    protected $username;
    protected $email;
    protected $pass;
    protected $dateAdded;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use `fetch_object('classes\Users')` ?

Comment: what happen it will work ha ha thanksssss.  Please add answer so I can choose yours.

Comment: I'd still like to figure out what it didn't hook into the name spacing you defined.

Comment: I'm using PSR-4  autoloader,  maybe it has some bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to specify the full namespace of your object

eg `fetch_object('classes\Users')`